# Gems are not working with rbenv despite being installed successfully

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

Ruby gems are not working even though they're supposed to be installed. For example, if I run `gem install pry` it runs successfully, but then if I run pry it says `command not found: pry`. I ran rbenv-doctor and it gave this output:

```
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK
Checking `rbenv install' support: ~/.config/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20211227-5-g4f1e62f)
Counting installed Ruby versions: 2 versions
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
```

I believe this happened originally because I tried moving rbenv to the .config directory. (At that point some gems were partially accessible) So then I completely uninstalled rbenv and its ruby versions and reinstalled, but the problem is still there.

I also ran `rbenv rehash`, it does nothing.

Also might help: if I run bundle in a rails directory it says `cannot load such file -- ~/.local/share/gem/gems/bundler-2.2.24/exe/bundle` -- there is a bundler in ~/.local/share/gem/gems/ but it's a different version.

Comment: I have similar problem with HTTParty... installs and I can load the gem from IRB but when I try running ruby script I get: 
  ``/home/pi/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- HTTParty (LoadError)``

not sure if the version number difference between 3.1.1 and 3.1.0 have anything to do with error

Comment: There is no shim for rails whatsoever, is there supposed to be?

Comment: Solved by uninstalling the system ruby. No idea what the problem was but apparently rbenv does not work if you have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after fiddling around with various installation methods of ruby and rbenv.

In my case, there was a `.bundle/config` file left from a previous attempt to install the gems locally (it contained `BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"`).

After removing this file and another `bundle install` everything worked like a charm again with rbenv.